# RANDOM_BYTES or CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM equivalent in MariaDB

Tags: random, mariadb

**Question**

Is any alternatives of MySQL `RANDOM_BYTES(len)` or MSSQL `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(len)` available in MariaDB?

I read through their documentation, but I only found is `rand(len)`, which is not cryptographically secure in generating random bytes.

**Issues**

Currently released version of MariaDB (10.3) does not support `RANDOM_BYTES(len)` according to this documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/function-differences-between-mariadb-103-and-mysql-57/

**Limitation**

If possible, keep the code within the MariaDB, and I don't want to rely on PHP or any other external functions for security reasons.

Comment: [`Random_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) in PHP 7 is cryptographically secure.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya well yes, with external language, it's possible. But what I want to achieve is to "Make the stored procedure stand alone". Usually my database is accessed by multiple-interfaces, some are PHP, or it could be .NET, and etc.

Comment: Did you find a native alternative by any chance?

Comment: @Elektropepi Not yet, and still is not supported with MariaDB10.4. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/function-differences-between-mariadb-104-and-mysql-80/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `RANDOM_BYTES(length)` is available since 10.10.0 (preview release) Check the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/random_bytes/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately from talking to MariaDB support there is currently no `RANDOM_BYTES` equivalent in MariaDB. See https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27002 for a semi-related ticket which has to do with generating random passwords for users.

To get around this, what you can do is create a custom UDF (user-defined function) in C which utilizes a cryptographically secure library to generate a random series of bytes for whatever use case you have. This technically keeps the code 'within MariaDB' though you need to write your own function to call. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-user-defined-functions/ for more info.